# error while running my project in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, kotlin

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i had changed  Kotlin version to = '1.8.20' but it is showing same error
i had added my firebase account through flutterfire configure and after that it is showing this error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74388473/14162959