# Flutter error: Lost connection to device. How to solve it?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I have this error that I've been stuck with for months. I have no idea what's causing it or how to go about solving it. Somehow it won't connect with the emulator. It's either this or "Error connecting to service protocol".

The error below:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.

Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 5440): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.

D/FlutterLocationService( 5440): Creating service.

D/FlutterLocationService( 5440): Binding to location service.

Lost connection to device.
```

What I've checked so far:

- Memory is enough
- flutter doctor -v shows no issues

Comment: Nope, using emulator

Comment: The issue seems to be with the implementation of your plugin, now with the device connection. There is some package that can not be bound with native channels thus breaking the connection. I'm pretty sure other projects would be working fine.

Comment: How do I go about solving it?

Comment: Hello. please do check this out on how solve this warning first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368175/why-am-i-getting-this-warning-and-how-to-resolve-it-this-version-only-understan.

Comment: Hi @Praveesh Ramroop I have exactly the same problem, did you found any solution? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue before. I was in the process of implementing notifications in my app using `firebase_messaging` and `flutter_local_notifications`. In the settings, a suggestion was made to include the following code snippets:

```
compileOptions {
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // ...
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
    // ...
}
```

After adding these lines, I started experiencing an error in the Flutter emulator: "Error connecting to service protocol." I tried a variety of troubleshooting steps, such as resetting the emulator, `flutter clear` `flutter tun`, updating all packages, and more. However, none of these solutions seemed to work.

The only thing that actually resolved the issue was removing the previously added lines. Once I removed those lines, I could connect again with the emulator. The notifications also worked without any problem.

I hope this information proves helpful to others facing a similar problem!

Comment: Does not work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was checking and I found out that this problem only happens (at least for me) on Android 12L.

I found this link with possible [solutions](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110658).

In my case, I had to enable desugaring in `android/app/build.gradle`, so I added the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the android studio,In android studio wipe the data of emulator and in flutter user **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get** command lines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).